# Replicating c# decompression algorithm in Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, gzip, zlib

I'm dealing with an external API(written in c#) which returns a gzip compressed string as input. My consumer is written in Ruby and I need to write the decompression logic in Ruby. They've provided me with a working c# snippet which successfully decompresses the string. I'm having trouble replicating the same in Ruby. The API response is Base64 encoded, and needs to be decoded before being passed into the Decompresser. I've managed to replicate this step in Ruby.

Here's the Base64 encoded compressed string that I'm working with

```
Input
DcixCYBADAXQVUJqwd5OFDsrJzjkIwG9kyQniDiZhSO5gtc93ve8F/fwIKtxc/HkwXMRD2WygiseYRYWlOuyedqgJEYxOSkWMYfW1KOdXQ6QRDpTVtpDxMr3/QM=

Expected Output
{"Details":{"Status":"Failure","Message":"Customer is not register/ DeActive in your panel"}}
```

C# code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strResult = "";
            byte[] input = Convert.FromBase64String("DcixCYBADAXQVUJqwd5OFDsrJzjkIwG9kyQniDiZhSO5gtc93ve8F/fwIKtxc/HkwXMRD2WygiseYRYWlOuyedqgJEYxOSkWMYfW1KOdXQ6QRDpTVtpDxMr3/QM=");
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}\n", BitConverter.ToString(input)); 
            using(MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(input)) {  
                    using(DeflateStream gzip = new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
                        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) {
                            strResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            Console.WriteLine(strResult);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Ruby code

```
require 'base64'
require 'stringio'
require 'zlib'
require 'open-uri'

def decompress(compressedstring)
    byte_array = Base64.decode64(compressedstring).unpack("C*")
    response = Zlib::Inflate.inflate(byte_array.join(""))
end
```

Right now the ruby code is throwing the following error

```
Zlib::DataError: incorrect header check
    from (irb):22:in `inflate'
    from (irb):22
    from /Users/gendalf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

===========================================

**Update**

I've managed to make some progress by using the following Ruby code

```
require 'base64'
require 'stringio'
require 'zlib'
require 'open-uri'

def decompress(compressedstring)
    decoded_string = Base64.decode64(compressedstring)
    zlib = Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS);
    zlib.inflate(decoded_string)
end

decompress("DcixCYBADAXQVUJqwd5OFDsrJzjkIwG9kyQniDiZhSO5gtc93ve8F/fwIKtxc/HkwXMRD2WygiseYRYWlOuyedqgJEYxOSkWMYfW1KOdXQ6QRDpTVtpDxMr3/QM=")
```

The output for the same looks like this

```
"\xEF\xBB\xBF{\"Details\":{\"Status\":\"Failure\",\"Message\":\"Customer is not register/ DeActive in your panel\"}}"
```

As mentioned in the comments, I can drop EFBBBF(UTF-8 BOM: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) and then parse the rest of the JSON. I think this solves my problem. It'll be great if someone can explain what's happening here in depth in order to help others in future. I've got it working but I'm not very sure about the actual workings.

Comment: You might need to change `"/"` characters to `"_"` and `"+"` characters to `"-"` in the base64 string before trying to decompress it in Ruby (if Ruby is using RFC 4648 as the encoding standard).

Comment: I think the decoding works successfully as the output is exactly similar to the c# code

Comment: EFBBBF is the UTF-8 BOM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

If you drop it, then the example will parse as JSON.
What other errors occur with the bigger API response?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Pascal. The bigger JSON response needed to be decrypted before the decompression, now I've got it working. Any non-hacky way of getting rid of that BOM?

Comment: Okay, just realized that the ruby JSON parser ignores it. So I think this solves my problem gracefully.